# Which win32 API can be used to listen on a port in windows?

Tags: winapi, windbg

I'm reverse engineering a software,and I set a bp on `listen`,doesn't work.

What other win32 APi are there to listen on a specific port?

And I know the port it's listenning on is `8888`.

**UPDATE**
What I'm doing is for this task:

How can I implement a http proxy server myself? Do I need to need to bother with TCP/IP protocols?

Comment: I would have figured with your "name" that you would be all over this.

Comment: @Tim Jarvis,it's an open source project,or put simply,how can I implement a http proxy server myself? Do I need to need to bother with TCP/IP protocols?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are asking is, how to implement a transparent proxy. In which case you can do it on one of two levels:

1. You can implement a local PC only transparent proxy, by injecting a hook dll into all processes, that hooks winsock calls, and intercepts traffic by directly monitoring connect, send, recv requests (and re-writing as necessary).
2. To implement a transparent proxy on a network, you a. need to have access to the gateway that the other PCs are routing their internet traffic through. b. You need to get a special library that works with raw sockets to intercept the traffic that should be routing through the gateway, and rerouting it to your local proxy server.

Typically this is done on Linux, rather than Windows, as Linux has a simple tool [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/), that can be used to "transparently" redirect traffic that was passing through a gateway, to a specific proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

OK, as well as my smart-arse comment (sorry about that, my attempt at humour) I'll do my best to point you to where you can start.

Sounds like what you are trying to do is packet "sniffing", you probably need to use the [WinPCap library](http://www.winpcap.org/) in order to filter and capture the packets before the listening app (i.e. your app as a proxy, intercepts and passes on / or not to the listening app) you will need to be down at the kernel level as far as I understand it. This library comes with a device driver that will allow you to do that.

Comment: He just ask what winapi function to listen on a port. Your answer just say nothing about it.

Comment: @WilliamTaylor umm, he didn't just ask that - his clarified question was how to implement a HTTP proxy server.